# Hide zero before decimal point

Tags: r

Writing an article with R + Sweave, I wish to hide the zero before decimal point for correlation results. For example, for a score of `0.85`, I wish to show it as `.85`. Or if the score is negative, e.g. `-0.85`, it should be shown as `-.85`.

Right now I am doing it in a very ugly way, using `substr(0.85, 2, 4)` for positive values and `paste("-", substr(-0.85, 3, 5), sep="")` for negative values. I did some homework, checking functions such as `format()` and `formatC` in the base package, but none of them seemed to meet my needs.

So I wonder whether there is an easier way to hide the zero before decimal point in R? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a regular expression:

```
sub('^(-)?0[.]', '\\1.', c(0.85, -0.85))
## [1] ".85"  "-.85"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This looks so much better, and also looks superior to the answer in the other thread :)